# pandas: first two elements in a string column matches dictionary key

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

I have a dataframe as follows:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'data1':['the weather is nice today','This is interesting','the weather is good'],
             'data2':['It is raining','The plant is green','the weather is sunny']})
```

and I have a dictionary as follows:

```
my_dict = {'the weather':'today','the plant':'tree'}
```

I would like to replace the first two words in the data2 column if they are found in the dictionary key. I have done the following:

```
for old, new in dic.items():    
    if pd.Series([' '.join(map(str, l)) for l in df['data2'].str.lower().str.split().map(lambda x: x[0:2])]).str.contains('|'.join(old.capitalize()).any():
       df['data2'] = df['data2'].str.replace(old, new.capitalize(), regex=False)
    else:
       print('does not exist')
```

but when i print(df), nothing has been replaced.

the expected output:

```
                       data1                 data2
0  the weather is nice today         It is raining
1        This is interesting    Tree is green
2        the weather is good    Today is sunny
```

Comment: What are you trying to do with the very long `if` statement? Also, do you want to replace `"The plant"` with `"tree"` even though the `"T"` is capitalised, which it isn't in the dictionary? If so, you also have to check `old.capitalize()`.

Comment: i added the expected output, thank you for the comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, this is one way to do it (there may be more efficient ways):

```
df.data2 = df.data2.str.lower()
for k in my_dict:
  df.data2 = df.data2.str[:len(k)].replace(k, my_dict[k]) + df.data2.str[len(k):]

df.data2 = df.data2.str.capitalize()
```

Lowercasing and capitalization weren't in your question but were part of your code, so I put them in (otherwise it would fail because the capitalization doesn't match in your sample code).

Answer (score 1):

1. use python map function to go through the arrays
2. in the dataframe we have like `The plant` and we are trying to compare it with `the plant` without converting it to lower case.

```
    for old, new in my_dict.items():    
    if pd.Series([' '.join(map(str, l)) for l in df['data2'].str.lower().str.split().map(lambda x: x[0:2])]).str.contains('|'.join(old)).any():
       df['data2'] = list(map(lambda x: x.lower().replace(old, new.capitalize()), df['data2']))
    else:
       print('does not exist')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try with [`pandas.Series.str.replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html)

```py
for key, val in my_dict.items():
    df['data2'] = df['data2'].str.replace(f'^{key}', val, case=False, regex=True)
```

```
print(df)

                       data1           data2
0  the weather is nice today   It is raining
1        This is interesting   tree is green
2        the weather is good  today is sunny
```